# finding location of HTML elements with javascript & offsettop

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-browser

I'm trying to find the location of an element on the screen using javascript. This is what I'm doing.

```
function locateTargets(){
    var targets = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for(var i = 0;i<targets.length;i++){
        if(targets[i].className == "target"){
            targetsY[targets[i].getAttribute("id")] = targets[i].offsetTop;
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine in Firefox, Chrome and IE, but Opera and Safari end up finding 0 for all but the last element.

Any ideas why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`offsetTop` finds the top location relative to the last absolutely-positioned parent/ancestor element (`document.body` is the first absolutely-positioned ancestor element for any other element).

It looks like [Opera has a bit of trouble](http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/ArticlePageOffset) with `document.body` and even [fixed elements](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/opera/bugs/PositionFixedoffsetTop).

If these are not your issues, posting a bit of code may help us help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I think this might be the issue, especially if Safari has similar problems. What throws me off is this:
I find seven elements with class="target". Six of them return 0 for their offsetTop, but the last one returns the correct value. So it DOES work somehow. Just not consistently. I double and triple checked the actual span tags and they are all identical (except for their ids of course).